# How to set keyboard shortcut for ButtonClick Event?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a windows form which saves data on ButtonClick event but I also want to execute this event when user presses some key board shortcut such as :
<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> 
to save.
I tried form's `KeyDown event` and `KeyPress event` but they just wont fire. 
I guess I am missing out something.

```
 Private Sub frmExchangeSymbolMapping_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyPress
        If Asc(e.KeyChar) = Keys.Control AndAlso Asc(e.KeyChar) = Keys.E Then
            MessageBox.Show("Testing")
        End If
    End Sub
```

I will accept c# answers too (If it can be converted to vb using online tools :P )

Answer (score 5):

Set the [`KeyPreview` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the form to `true`. This will register all the key events with the form itself first and, if no shortcut is found, with the currently focused component.

Comment: also use http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(v=vs.110).aspx to know if contol pressed

Answer (score 1):

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, ByVal keyData As Keys) As Boolean
    Select Case msg.Msg
        Case &H100, &H104
            Select Case keyData
                Case Keys.Control Or Keys.E
                  MessageBox.Show("Control + E Pressed")
                  Exit Select
            End Select
      Exit Select
    End Select
    Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
End Function
```

Comment: You Can Also Try Adding Menu Strip And Add Shortcut To that Event

Answer (score 0):

My Solution is here in **C#**.

**1.** Set your `Form` `KeyPreview` Property to `true`.
**2.** Subscribe to the `KeyDown` Event of the `Form` as below:

```
this.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.Form1_KeyDown);
```

**3.** handle the `KeyDown` event of `Form` as below:

```
    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control  && e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
            MessageBox.Show("Ctrl + S pressed!");
    }
```

**Complete Code:**

```
this.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.Form1_KeyDown);
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Control  &&  e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
       MessageBox.Show("Ctrl + S pressed!");
}
```

Comment: Where exactly do I have to put `Me.KeyDown += New System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(Me.Form1_KeyDown)` Because I am getting error at `Me`

Comment: @Arbaaz: you can add that statement in form load.

Comment: `Error 9 'Public Event KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs)' is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event`

Comment: @Arbaaz: did you put this statement -> `this.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.Form1_KeyDown);` inside FormLoad?

Answer (score 0):

If you set the Text for the button to &Save Alt-S will click the button assuming there isn't a menu intercepting the Ctrl-S.